# Установка убунты с флешки на ноут

Tags: usb, ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить убунту на ноутбук с флешки (в ноуте нет привода). Мне посоветовали две утилитки для установки убунты с флешки (первую благополучно забыл, вторая - LiLi USB Creator). Вроде процесс создания проходит нормально, но при запуске с флешки на ноуте (через бут меню) у меня появляется черный экран и мигающий курсор. И ничего. И так было на обеих утилитах. Кто может знать, в чем проблема?Так же сделал все по инструкции отсюда: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/downloadТот же самый результат...

Comment: Пробовали на другом компьютере с этой самой флешки загрузиться? И что сейчас стоит на ноутбуке?

Comment: пробовал на самом компьютере, в бут меню просто не нахожу флешки

Comment: возможно, нужно включить/выключить uefi в настройках биоса . На работающей системе не переключайте - в 99% случаев это не даст загрузиться установленной системе.

Comment: какую версию ubuntu вы пытаетесь установить?

Answer (score 1):

Для установки линукс на ноутбук с флешки, используй программу Unetbootin.Там же в ней можно слить образ, и сразу залить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

1. альтернативную установку (в текстовом режиме),
2. установку с предыдущих версий убунту,
3. установку с другой флэшки (может она сбоит).

Перед установкой проверьте целостность образа с помощью MD5 хэш-сумм.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что загрузочная флешка не получилась. По крайней мере, мигающий курсор на чёрном фоне у меня получался на некоторых компьютерах, когда пытался их перезагрузить не вытащив обычную флешку.

А для создания live usb (правда, с Mint'ом), использовал http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/.